# Apply JQuery resize function to all different DIV-IDs in my container

Tags: jquery, resize

I have a container in a HTML file. In this container are several DIVs with different sizes. I want to resize these DIVs when I resize my browser window. I currently have this function in my HTML, which apply to the DIV with the classname "draggable". It works obviously for all DIVs, but take one width. I want this function applies to the different DIV-IDs, so the width for each DIV is calculated accordingly to its DIV-width.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var originaContainerWidth = $('.visible-container').width();
    console.log("original container width");
    console.log(originaContainerWidth);
    var cardWidth = $('.draggable').width();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var resizedContainerWidth = $('.visible-container').width();
        console.log("resized container width");
        console.log(resizedContainerWidth);
        var percentageResized = resizedContainerWidth / originaContainerWidth
        console.log("percentage width");
        console.log(percentageResized);
        console.log("cardWidth");
        console.log(cardWidth);
        var resizedCardWidth = (cardWidth * percentageResized);
        console.log("resizedCardWidth");
        console.log(resizedCardWidth);
        $('.draggable').css("width", resizedCardWidth + "px");

        originaContainerWidth = resizedContainerWidth
        cardWidth = resizedCardWidth

    });
});
</script>
```

How can I apply this function to the different DIV-IDs and not to their classname?

Edit HTML:

```
<div class="inner-container" id="innerContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

    <div class="draggable" id="7" data-x="7" data-y="47" style="width: 362.891px; height: 129.484px; transform: translate(7px, 47px); background-color: rgb(245, 221, 103) !important;">

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between card-title">
            <div style="width: 20px; height:22px;">
            <button data-toggle="modal" id="cardEdit" data-placement="left" title="Edit" class="edit existingCard" data-card_text="" data-card_title="Backlog" data-card_id="7" data-card_color="#f5dd67"><i class="fas fa-edit" style="color: #007bff;"></i></button>
                </div>

            <div class="mx-auto">
                <span>Backlog</span>
            </div>

            <div style="width: 20px; height:22px;" class="pr-4">
                <form method="post">
                    <button name="deleteCard" class="edit" type="submit" value="7"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" style="color: #cc0000;"></i></button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="text-container">
                <textarea class="textarea-resizing" readonly="" style="height:40px;overflow-y:hidden;" id="text"></textarea>
            </div>
    </div>

    
    <div class="draggable" id="8" data-x="9" data-y="234" style="width: 362.891px; height: 158px; transform: translate(9px, 234px); background-color: rgb(245, 221, 103) !important; border: none;">

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between card-title">
            <div style="width: 20px; height:22px;">
            <button data-toggle="modal" id="cardEdit" data-placement="left" title="Edit" class="edit existingCard" data-card_text="" data-card_title="Second Kart" data-card_id="8" data-card_color="#f5dd67"><i class="fas fa-edit" style="color: #007bff;"></i></button>
                </div>

            <div class="mx-auto">
                <span>Second Kart</span>
            </div>

            <div style="width: 20px; height:22px;" class="pr-4">
                <form method="post">
                    <button name="deleteCard" class="edit" type="submit" value="8"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" style="color: #cc0000;"></i></button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="text-container">
                <textarea class="textarea-resizing" readonly="" style="height:40px;overflow-y:hidden;" id="text"></textarea>
            </div>
    </div>

    

</div>
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would show us the relevant html code

Comment: added the relevant container and draggable html code